# The colors on videos I watch are messed up - quite badly

Tags: nautilus, video, totem, colors

This one really has me stumped. Whenever I watch a video in Totem or VLC, the colors are completely messed up. Here is the preview of a video in Nautilus and what it looks like in Totem:

[image]

Some other helpful information:

- This does not happen for videos in the Flash player.
- This happens for all video formats, including MPEG / WMV / etc.
- I am using Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit with the Nvidia driver 270.41.06.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special thanks to [Stefano](https://askubuntu.com/users/1067/stefano-palazzo) for suggesting what ultimately led to the solution:

Somehow, it seems that the hue slider in Totem was not set properly and that was what was messing up the colors. It would also seem that the problem was affecting every single application with video output as well since the problem manifested itself in VLC, Cheese, etc.

The solution was to simply reset the sliders to their default values and now everything works.

Comment: what slider??????????????

Comment: Oh I see, under Edit/preferences. Ok, not my case, my slider is fine, yet the colors are messed up.